# geraten - Partizip

Tags: meaning

Wo liegt eigentlich der Unterschied zwischen

*ein kleiner Mensch*

und

*ein  klein geratener Mensch*?

Ich habe versucht *geraten* in verschiedenen Wörterbücher nachzuschlagen, nur um die Bedeutung des Verbs festzustellen, was aber nicht besonders hilfreich war.

Comment: Würde man wahrscheinlich beides nicht sagen; _kleiner Mensch_ vielleicht noch in bestimmten Zusammenhängen für ein Kleinkind.

Comment: Ich denke "ein kleiner Mensch" ist relativ allgemein, klein geraten wird eher mit der Bedeutung kleiner als die Norm/Standard üblich benutzt, nicht selten -je nach Zusammenhang- auch zum verhöhnen.

Comment: In my opinion *geraten* puts more emphasis on the production process than in the result, like *der Kuchen ist etwas dunkel greaten*. Its not a sort of small-scale comparative.

Comment: *geraten* baut für mich eher "das Element des Zufalls" oder das "Misslingen eines Plans" ins *Werden* ein.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*ein kleiner Mensch* ist, was es sagt - Ein Mensch, der klein ist, u.U. auch ein Kind.

*Klein geraten* heisst: Hätte eigentlich größer werden sollen, ist aber entgegen aller Planung kleiner ausgefallen. Wertend ist das nicht unbedingt, ausser man betrachtet das mögliche Misslingen des ursprünglichen "Plans" als negativ.

Bei Menschen kann das nun bedeuten, dass die vom Plan abweichende Größe entweder von der betroffenen Person selbst als "Misslingen" betrachtet wird (der Mensch sich also selbst als *zu klein* empfindet und evtl. Komplexe deswegen hat) oder dass jemand anderes, z.B. die Eltern, deswegen unzufrieden/unglücklich sind.

Der Begriff kann als fast bedeutungsgleich mit "klein geworden" (mit einer Prise "Zufall" oder "ohne den Vorgang beeinflusst zu haben") betrachtet werden, das Verb ist *geraten* (ist Infinitiv, auch wenn es so aussieht wie ein Partizip) und hat mit *raten* nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 3):

Mein persönlicher Eindruck ist, dass „klein geraten“ eine Wertung beinhaltet und ein einfaches „klein“ nicht zwangsweise. Ein Kuchen ist „klein geraten“, wenn er laut Rezept oder Bild größer hätte sein müssen. Ein Kuchen kann aber auch klein sein, obwohl das Ergebnis den Erwartungen entspricht.

Vielleicht noch ein anderes Beispiel, um meine Meinung zu verdeutlichen:
Ein Kind ist vom Standpunkt des Erwachsenen klein. Das Kind kann sogar klein sein, obwohl es für sein Alter ziemlich groß ist. Klein geraten ist deshalb nicht jedes Kind, erst wenn es kleiner als die Norm ist.

Answer (score 3):

Ich möchte das Augenmerk auf das Partizip "geraten" lenken, was laut Duden soviel bedeutet wie

> ohne Absicht, zufällig an eine bestimmte Stelle, irgendwohin gelangen 
>   in einen bestimmten Zustand, eine bestimmte Lage kommen
>   am Ende einer Herstellung bestimmte Eigenschaften aufweisen, ausfallen

Bezogen auf Dein konkretes Beispiel, kann man also von einem Menschen sprechen, der am Ende der "Herstellung", d.h. seines bisherigen Wachstumsprozesses, klein (also kleiner als der Durchschnitt) ist.
Wo ist jetzt der Unterschied zur Aussage "kleiner Mensch"? Durch den Zusatz des Partizips wird

1. die Bedeutung von "klein" als "körperlich klein" hervorgehoben
2. der komparative Charakter des Adjektivs verstärkt

Beispiel: mit "kleiner Mensch" muss nicht unbedingt eine körperlich kleine Person gemeint sein, es kann sich auch um ein Kind handeln. "klein" kann hier die Nebenbedeutung "jung" annehmen. Durch den Zusatz "geraten" wird das ausgeschlossen.

Dass "klein geraten" als Ausdruck an sich eine Wertung beinhaltet, sehe ich nicht. Allerdings ist die Begriffsbildung in diesem Kontext ("Mensch") ungewöhnlich, weswegen sie sich eignet, um Ironie oder sogar einen abwertenden Unterton einfließen zu lassen.

Answer (score 1):

"Klein" ist eine eher absolute Aussage; ein "kleiner Mensch" wäre also - je nach Kontext - am unteren Ende der normalen Größen eines Menschen zu suchen.

"Klein geraten" ist in gewisser Weise eine Form der Verniedlichung, d.h. "kleiner als üblich" aber noch nicht "sehr klein". (Hat also absolut nichts mit "Raten" zu tun.)

Konkret: Wenn normale Männer 1,80m groß sind (Annahme), würde ich "klein geraten" bei etwa 1,65-1,70m einsortieren, und "klein" bei weniger als 1,65m. (Aber das ist eine persönliche Interpratation und hängt sehr vom Kontext ab. Spricht man beispielsweise über Kleinwüchsige, dann liegt die Messlatte sicherlich anders.)

Comment: Also klein geraten kenne ich eher nicht als Verniedlichung. Vor allem -so weit mir bekannt ist- wird es eher in einem höhnischen Kontext benutzt!

Comment: Ich habe gerade einmal in meinem Umkreis nachgefragt, wie "klein geraten" interpretiert wird. Es ist offenbar eine sehr individuelle Sache und auch stark vom jeweiligen Kontext abhängig. Mal wird es verniedlichend angenommen (aber in der Tat eher selten), mal als neutral (also nur den reinen Sachverhalt beschreibend - "klein geraten" im (neutralen) Sinne von "nicht sehr groß gewachsen"), mal belächelnd/spöttisch/höhnisch.

Ich denke, mit dieser allgemeinen Aussage dürfte dem OP geholfen sein... hoffe ich zumindest :-)